# Android Instant App - Play Console release/deploy error and DAL(digital Asset Link) not linked

Tags: android, applinks, android-instant-apps, google-play-console, digital-assets-links

I'm trying to figure out why the play store will not accept my instant app build. I have successfully deployed an **Alpha** regular app release to testers since it is a prerequisite to release an instant app. I am trying to deploy a **development** release instant app. What am I doing wrong? I tried to add as much detail as possible.

Do I need to use the Digital Asset Link API service at the following link for a production instant app or is that for something else?
 https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/overview

I get the following error when uploading the instant app build to the play console:

> Your site 'example.com' has not been linked through the Digital
>   Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the
>   Digital Assets Link protocol to your app.

One thing i'm a little confused about is why when I click **link and verify** that a get the error message "*Adding asset statements failed.*" as shown in the following picture:
[image: Adding asset statements failed]
I notice that when I click the **link and verify** button, it modifies the strings.xml file in *base* and adds the following string: `<string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">[{\n  \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],\n  \"target\": {\n    \"namespace\": \"web\",\n    \"site\": \"https://example.com\",\n  }\n}]</string>`

I have the following in the manifest of *base*, *checklist* and *advisor* under the application tag: `<meta-data android:name="asset_statements" android:resource="@string/asset_statements"/>`

**Project description and structure:**

*App description*: This is a proof of concept app. The installable app will open the mainfeature activity with two buttons that will bring you to either the checklist or advisor activity when clicked. There are two instant apps, instantapp-checklist goes to the checklist activity and instantapp(advisor) goes to the advisor activity.

- There are 3 feature modules: mainfeature, checklist, advisor
- There are 2 instant apps: instantapp-checklist, instantapp(advisor)

[image: Project structure]

- My installable app's bundle is is: blah.blah1.blah2.myappname
- My checklist instant app's bundle id is: blah.blah1.blah2.myappname.checklist
- My advisor instant app's bundle id is: blah.blah1.blah2.myappname.advisor

My assetlinks.json is:

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "blah.blah1.blah2.myappname.checklist",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["AA:...:53"]
  }
},
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "blah.blah1.blah2.myappname.advisor",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["AA:...:53"]
  }
}]
```

In my checklist manifest inside the activity tag is the following:

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="default-url"
            android:value="https://example.com/checklist.html"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:order="1"
                       android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/checklist.html"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

**Self checks I've done:**

- The instant app was signed signed with my keystore, not with the debug key. I checked to make sure the instant app's and the assetlinks.json show the same sha256 fingerprint.
- The robots.txt allows assetlinks.json to be searched by all robots
- assetlinks.json does have a valid cert and allows https
- The content-type of assetlinks.json header is application/json
- I am not opt'd in for "Google Play App Signing"
- I used the following site to test my statement and it is successful: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

Comment: Any chance you opt’d in for “Google Play App Signing” under “[app] > Release management > App signing” ?  (and no, you don’t need Digital Asset Link API)

Comment: Otherwise, can you file a bug, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: @TWL I am not opt'd in for Google Play App Signing

Comment: There's likely some site/key/manifest mismatch going on, but it will be hard to check it out without exposing this info here. I would suggest Google's issue tracker since the debug might involve sharing this private data.

Comment: Just noticed! It is because of the `package_name` in your `assetlinks.json`. The package name should be the package name of the app itself: `blah.blah1.blah2.myappname`

Comment: @TWL I added one object to the _assetlinks.json_ file with the installable package_name(`blah.blah1.blah2.myappname`) so now the _assetlinks.json_ has 3 objects in the array. I was able to successfully release a development build now!

Comment: @TWL I then became a development tester after clicking the button on instant app opt-in URL site successfully. When I go to chrome and type in the instant app URL it just opens the web page, not the instant app. I asked Google Support via chat, they said it can take a few to 48 hours for the instant app to be available to test. I'll keep in touch with any further updates!

Comment: @TWL The instant app now works! Here's one strange thing though.. If I'm in Chrome and type in the URL it doesn't seem to open the instant app, only the web site. If I am in Chrome and click on a link on a website to the URL, it does prompt me to open the instant app. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That is correct. Typing the URL into the address bar will not launch Instant Apps. They are supposed to be launched by clicking on links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **assetlinks.json** file, the field *package_name* is set to *blah.blah1.blah2.myappname.checklist*.

However, mentioned above is that the **installable app's id** is *blah.blah1.blah2.myappname*. That means the *package_name* in the *AndroidManifest.xml* is set to *blah.blah1.blah2.myappname*.

They should match. *blah.blah1.blah2.myappname* must be added to the *assetlinks.json* on the server.

In the *strings.xml*, change the asset_statements:

```
<string name="asset_statements" translatable="false">[{\n  \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],\n  \"target\": {\n    \"namespace\": \"web\",\n    \"site\": \"https://qaapps.cio.ny.gov/apps/sandbox/james/hesc/checklist.html\",\n  }\n},{\n  \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],\n  \"target\": {\n    \"namespace\": \"web\",\n    \"site\": \"https://qaapps.cio.ny.gov/apps/sandbox/james/hesc/advisor.html\",\n  }\n}]</string>
```

Here are some other notes that helped me find the solution:

- I used the following command line to test if the instant app works: `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://example.com/checklist/"`
- On the device, I went to *Settings > Google > Instant Apps* and clicked the switch to uninstall/turn-off instant apps, then click it again to turn it back on . Also went to the Chrome settings(*Settings > Privacy > Clear Browsing Data*) to clear all data for time range, All Time.
- When typing in the url to the instant app in Chrome, it only opens the website and not the instant app. If I click on a link to the instant app in a website it does open the instant app instead of the website.

Comment: why have you added different https://qaapps.cio.ny.gov/apps/sandbox/james/hesc/advisor.html URL here? other than assetlink.json ?

Comment: @olearyj234 bor same problem for me also Asset statements failed how to solve this can u guide me clearly

Answer (score 0):

It is weird, I had same problem. The solution was simple;

As @olearyj234 mentioned Link and Verify button adds string to end of string.xml.

I simply deleted the new string in string.xml and clicked the "Link and Verify" button.