# Digital Assets Link protocol to my website not working

Tags: java, android, android-instant-apps

While I try to publish my instant app in play store it showing that

Your site 'app.mydomain.in' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app.

But I linked the Digital Asset Link to my website But  Still Showing This  error
I am using App sign key which in play console and also  While Test with 
https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

showing good but trying to Roll to productions  it showing this error please help me

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: A couple posts you can check up on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46003617/6668797, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44633060/6668797, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46138747/6668797

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem after changing digital asset file permissions to public

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue in the asset link generator.

Use below format.

```
[
   { 
      "relation":[ 
                  "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
                 ],
      "target":{
                  "namespace":"web",
                  "site":"https://abc.xyz.com" 
               }
   },
   {
     "relation":[
                 "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
                ],
     "target":{
                  "namespace":"android_app",
                  "package_name":"com.ddd.app",
                  "sha256_cert_fingerprints":[ "ff:32:58:3A:CD:D8:57:9F:FB:C1:d3:88:33:44:FB:5B:33:15:33:33:8F:8A:3A:27:33:54:BE:33:7D:5D:4r:D7"
                                              ]
              }
     }
```

]